# WINSCP Diffie-hellman group 1 issue

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, winscp

I'm Trying to copy files my PC to a Linux device using **WINSCP** and when I try to do so, I am getting the below mentioned errors.

`The first key-exchange algorithm supported by the server is diffie-hellman-group1-sha1, which is below the configured warning threshold.`

```
Do you want to continue with this connection? file protocol in WINSCP is SFTP
```

I have no idea why this error is coming?

I made some troubleshooting like shifting the `Diffie-hellman group 1` above the warn level in the Advance Site Settings > SSH > Key exchnage

Please note in WINSCP am using the **SFTP** File protocol. I am able to connect to the device. But not able to transfer the files.

Any Help for this issue will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The *diffie-hellman-group1-sha1* warning has nothing to do with you *"not able to transfer the files"* - So what do you want to solve? The warning about *diffie-hellman-group1-sha1*? Or the problem with transferring files?

Answer (score -2):

**The issue got Solved:** The issue is with the WinSCP version. I was using the latest WinSCP version ([WinSCP-5.13.2-Setup.exe](https://winscp.net/download/WinSCP-5.13.2-Setup.exe)) it dint worked. But when I tried with an Old WinSCP version ([WinSCP-5.9.6-Setup.exe](https://winscp.net/download/WinSCP-5.9.6-Setup.exe)) it works fine.

Comment: That's not much of a solution. The warning (not an error; a warning) is legitimate and it's there as a security feature, telling you that your server's configuration is a bit obsolete.